# how to add space b/w twig condition

Tags: php, contentful, twig-extension

I am running contentful+symphony framework application on Heroku, on heroku twig remove space b/w the conditions.

**Twig Code**:   `<section class="block block--partners {% if transactionClass %}block--partners-transaction{% endif %}">`

**Results me to**: `<section class="block block--partnersblock--partners-transaction">` : removes space b/w classes, that happens on server only, on dev machine its working fine, any solution for this??

**Desired result**: `<section class="block block--partners block--partners-transaction">`

Any solution for that??

Answer (score 0):

Why not use twig to print the class name?

```
<section class="block block--partners {% if transactionClass %}{{ ' block--partners-transaction' }}{% endif %}">
```

Comment: yes this may be the last option, but on my dev machine its working absolutely fine, i have a large application to change the code by this solution. Problem is that on local machine this code is running fine, i am facing error on Production mode.

Comment: Have you checked this: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#whitespace-control